# MySQL Procedure Not Working

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, null, procedure

I'm working with procedures for the first time in MySQL, but for some reason I keep getting NULL. My test procedure is a simple one, it just adds.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure adds(in r double, out a double)
begin
set a = r + r;
end $$
delimiter ;

CALL adds(5, @a);

SELECT @a;
```

Not sure if I'm doing this right. For `@a` it just prints out NULL.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? This works fine in 5.0.

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench as the interface. I know I have the current version because I just recently downloaded MySQL. http://www.flickr.com/photos/68988543@N07/6272956375/

Comment: Fixed it! Did not set the default schema.

Answer (score 0):

A procedure is linked to a database.
You have not specified one, and therefor it will probably be attached to a different database than the one you are expecting.

When you change databases, MySQL will not longer find your stored procedure because it only looks in the correct DB.

**Remember to always specify your database when declaring a stored proc**

```
create procedure mydatabase.adds(in r double, out a double)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```